# How to pass several arguments to a function from a list in Python line by line

Tags: python, arguments, newline

I have a list with numbers.
List has 3 groups  of numbers followed by new line \n
I want to take 3 first group of numbers and pass them  to a function, then the next group

```
list = ['4', '23', '21\n20', '29', '30\n23', '11', '5' ........]

function (a,b,c)
     #do something with the numbers
```

Comment: No, you have a list of strings. Where did that list come from?

Comment: This list was created by me . I had  a  group of numbers : 
        2x7x7
        5X9x13
        8x7x13
I  split them with "x" symbol and i  get a list on strngs. I see where the problem is,  they must be integers and not strings :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should've split your data up into lines, then you can split each line with `.split('x')`. That makes it a bit simpler to get the data in the form you want. For example,

```
data = '''4x23x21
20x29x30
23x11x5
'''

def func(a, b, c):
    print('a=', a, 'b=', b, 'c=', c, 'sum=', a + b + c)

for row in data.splitlines():
    a, b, c = [int(u) for u in row.split('x')]
    func(a, b, c)
```

**output**

```
a= 4 b= 23 c= 21 sum= 48
a= 20 b= 29 c= 30 sum= 79
a= 23 b= 11 c= 5 sum= 39
```

That `for` loop & function call can be simplified using the `*` "splat" operator:

```
for row in data.splitlines():
    args = [int(u) for u in row.split('x')]
    func(*args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to split every element containing a \n:

```
list2 = [i.split('\n') for i in list]
list2 = [y for x in list2 for y in x]
```

Then call function every three elements:

```
for i in range(len(list2)):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        function(list2[i], list2[i+1], list2[i+2])
```